# Distribution determined by its cgf

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus

It is well known, that if the domain of the mgf $M:=E[e^{uX}]$ of a random variable $X$ contains an interval around zero, then the distribution is completely determined by its moments.

Consider the cumulant generating function $k:=\log E[e^{uX}]$ with domain $D_t$. Of course $0 \in D_t$. Assume moreover $D_t$ is an intervall. 
Can we already say, that the cumulant transform completely determines its distribution?

According to a statement of Jacod, Shiryaev  Limit theorems for stochastic processes p. 612 mentoined in 2.3 Proposition, this should hold

We may have a process with domain $[0,\infty)$, which doesn't contain an interval around zero.

If not, with the assumptions of $D_t$ above, can we say, that if all moments of $X$ exists, then $k$ determines the distribution of $X$?

Comment: Don't you have $D_t $ going out to $-\infty $ for free? Or is $X $ complex valued?

Comment: $X$ is real valued. What you mean by to $-\infty$ for free

Comment: When would a negative number not be in $D_t $? (This is seeming trivial to me since $M=e^k $, so I think I am missing something obvious.)

Comment: You could have a Levy process which has only positive jumps

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. When we say "domain" of the moment generating function or the cumulant generating function, we mean domain in the variable $u$. It has nothing directly to do with the possible values of $X$.

Comment: Yeah these values $u$ for which the expectation is finite. However we have to take care of the measure under $X$.

Comment: Watch the log normal distribution. The domain of the mgf is the negagive half line

Comment: Your example doesn't help actually, what you wanted to think of was the negative of a lognormal r.v. Anyway, I understand how you would have a r.v. whose mgf has no negative values in its domain. But if the domain of the mgf doesn't include any negative values, then you have (roughly speaking) very large negative values. So you should not necessarily expect moment reconstruction to work. (I'm still not really sure what stochastic processes have to do with any of this.)

Comment: Note that characteristic function reconstruction always does work...

Comment: In the literature cited there are also no assumptions made about the interval form. Just saying that having an interval as domain of the mgf is enough to determine the distribution. Of course 0 is in. But there is nothing else said. This is why i am a bit confused

Comment: You need $0$ to be in the interior of the domain of the mgf, otherwise there may not even be any moments to generate.

Comment: @Ian as you mentoined: i'm still not really sure what stochastic process have go do with any of this. Well this is basically that the domain of the mgf  of $X_t$ of a levy process is the same for each$t$. But this is basically a very special case. And i thought of levy processes in the general case mentioned above, where one may have a levy process where for $X_t$ the domain is a positive or negative half line?

Comment: But ok, i see that there is no way to get rid of the interval around 0